# Why are the images on my website still displayed in ascending order by id even though I am using order by id desc?

Tags: php, mysql

I ran the query on my database and it returned the correct descending order, however, on my website the images are still displayed in ascending order. I want the images with higher ID to be displayed on top of the page.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div class='imageContainer'>"
            ."<h1>".$row["name"].'</h1>'
            .'<a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a>
            </div>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: that seems very strange, does changing to `ORDER BY id ASC` actually inverse your images order?

Comment: No, tried both ascending and descending and the result is always the same.

Comment: and your database result is affected by the change? like when you `var_dump($row)` in the loop?

Comment: var_dump($row) returns the same thing either way. It's really strange because when I go to phpmyadmin -> sql and then execute the query, it returns the record in descending order but not on my website.

Comment: Print_r($result) . check what was the return in asc and desc ?

Comment: The result of Print_r($result) is the same for every image no matter if it's ordered by ascending or descending.

Comment: its working correctly for my test database and table. can you print your table data.?

Comment: What do you mean by print my table data?

Comment: can you print  schema of image table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150946/discussion-between-shashikant-and-peter-atanasov).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do I do that? I assume schema of image table would be the columns, correct?

Comment: can you come in to chat?

Comment: I'm in the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution. it is working in my system. please have a look and let me know.if any more errors comes.
In this i used object of database connection.
and method i used  $result->fetch_assoc(). Here is link for more info on this method : [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php](http://fetch_assoc)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // echo "<div class='imageContainer'><h1>".$row["name"]."'</h1><a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a></div>";
        echo "<div class='imageContainer'>"
            ."<h1>".$row["name"].'</h1>'
            .'<a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a>
            </div>'; 

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did differently?  To help people in the future who have a similar issue

Comment: Ans Updated @jeffUK

Comment: Interesting, any idea why fetch_assoc works in this case and fetch_array doesn't? Everying I read suggest that `order by` should work just fine with `mysqli_fetch_array`